# Mottie's Virtual Keyboard: direct input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, virtual-keyboard

There is an excellent jQuery on-screen keyboard plugin by Mottie:
https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

By default text from the keyboard goes into additional input and then can be accepted or cancelled. If text is accepted it goes into the source textarea/input.

But is there a way to input directly from the keyboard to the source textarea/input without the need to accept it (like with mobile keyboards on android/ios)?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki) for the plugin is contained in GitHub wiki pages.

The option needed not include a preview is called `usePreview` ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Usability#usepreview)); set it to `false` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MK947/2176/)):

To autoaccept the contents, set the [`autoAccept` option](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Usability#autoaccept) to `true`

```
$('#keyboard').keyboard({
    layout: 'qwerty',

    // true: preview added above keyboard;
    // false: original input/textarea used
    usePreview: false

    // Auto-accept content when clicking outside the
    // keyboard (popup will close)
    autoAccept: true

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't get how I missed this one)

Comment: If this is for android, you might need to set the `lockInput` option to `true` making the input readonly ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/204#issuecomment-27002297)) and thus preventing the mobile keyboard from opening.

Comment: Hello @Mottie,
If I use these settings then its not working. I have to use alwaysOpen  bit to true but autoAccept is not working with that.     
{ $('#keyboard').keyboard({
            layout: 'qwerty',
            alwaysOpen: true,
            usePreview   : false,
            autoAccept   : true,
            appendLocally: true
          
        }).addTyping();
    };
}